# Angular-Slickgrid showing blank records

Tags: angular, slickgrid

I am trying to show grid option in my application using [angular slickgrid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-slickgrid). I have referred [wiki page](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/HOWTO---Step-by-Step) to show grid but no data displaying in grid & even there is no error in browser console.

I have updated my app.module, Angular.json according to [post](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/HOWTO---Step-by-Step) but no use & grid displaying 0 records. I tried to create this problem using [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frcjjp) but its not allowing me to install angular-slickgrid package so unable to post live sample.

My code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Column, FieldType, Formatter, Formatters, GridOption }  from 'angular-slickgrid';

export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {
  columnDefinitions: Column[];
  gridOptions: GridOption;
  dataset: any[];

  ngOnInit(): void  
  {        
    this.gridOptions = {
      autoResize: {
        containerId: 'demo-container',
        sidePadding: 15
      },
      enableAutoResize: false,
      enableExcelCopyBuffer: true,

    };

    this.columnDefinitions = [
      { id: 'title', name: 'Title', field: 'title', sortable: true, type: FieldType.string, width: 70 }              
    ];

    this.dataset = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {    
      this.dataset[i] = {
        id: i, 
        title: 'Task ' + i
      };

    }

  }

}
```

My html

```
 <angular-slickgrid gridId="grid2" style="width:95%;"
                [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
                [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                [dataset]="dataset">
            </angular-slickgrid>
```

Version I am using:
**jquery**: ^3.3.1 **angular-slickgrid**: ^2.1.5 **@angular/core**: ^7.2.0

Comment: I'm the author of Angular-Slickgrid library and @JustCode solution would work but I would point out that you can also use the `[gridHeight]` (in the View) if you wish to define your own height and that can be used with or without the `enableAutoResize` (when `gridHeight` is set then it won't resize the height but would still resize the width). Also I added a [commit](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/commit/a190d3c026cb21d59ebaf9cfdcbea1802217ed3a) to address your issue, it will now throw an error if you omit to fill any of these 2 properties mention earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because you are using

```
enableAutoResize: false,
```

change it to

```
enableAutoResize : true
```

and it should work, when you work with false you need to give a height (using css) manually to the grid as per your needs. but when you allow true it will automatically set the size and resize on the browser resize.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjhehr)

Comment: ohhh! It was so simple but I invested many hours. Thanks a lot @justcode. its working now

Comment: interesting, I should probably had a check (or throw a console error) in my lib to make sure user has at least one or the other (some grid sizes or the autoResize enabled). I might consider it in future enhancement.